# Testing an API that requires signed requests

Tags: api, security, testing

I have an API that, until now, our QA person has been testing black-box style using Postman and our internal API docs.

This has worked fine, but now I've adjusted the API to require signed requests, which obviously means the QA person can't test without somehow generating a signature. Is there kind of a standard way of handling this? Any ideas?

Comment: How is the signature generated?

Comment: By concatenating all the args with a shared secret and hashing the result.

Comment: Is the secret the same for all user accounts? Is creating an account for the tester not feasible?

Comment: Yes, the secret is universal, but the hash will be unique as a function of the argument values, so it's not like one signature would work for all requests, and plus the signature generation happens under the hood.

Comment: One idea I had was to write a separate program that the QA person could use to generate his own signatures, but I wanted to check first to see if there might be a better way to do it.